# pyodbc executemany is not batching insert - SQL server insert is very slow

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have an application reading from local log which constitutes of JSON objects on each line. It parses each line and attempts insert to SQL server DB. The SQL server is running in Azure as PaaS offering.

I dropped foreign keys on DB to speed up the insert, but the performance is extremely slow.

I did profiling in python and found out below. Notice the execute call, each is taking 60 ms.

```
Mon May 14 20:05:05 2018    logparserprof.out

         385055 function calls (384911 primitive calls) in 1832.423 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     11/1    0.000    0.000 1832.423 1832.423 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000 1832.423 1832.423 logparsers.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.212    0.212 1831.728 1831.728 logparsers.py:282(parse)
    12796    0.030    0.000 1816.892    0.142 logparsers.py:240(parse_event)
    30432 1814.571    0.060 1814.571    0.060 {method 'execute' of 'pyodbc.Cursor' objects}
    12471    0.014    0.000 1796.979    0.144 logparsers.py:232(parse_event_Task)
```

So I decided to batch request and saw the `executemany` call and ran again with similar speed. ( I tried to batch every 1000-1500 record inserts )

I profiled again and **executemany** was taking 46 seconds!

```
Tue May 15 00:55:46 2018    logparserprof2.out

         384660 function calls (384516 primitive calls) in 1659.800 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       35 1635.272   46.722 1635.272   46.722 {method 'executemany' of 'pyodbc.Cursor' objects}
      335   20.095    0.060   20.095    0.060 {method 'execute' of 'pyodbc.Cursor' objects}
```

I looked at resmon in Windows to check network latency and found out the average is 57-60 ms.

My next step was to attempt to perform multi-threading and adding parallelism to the application wherever possible for inserts. However, I want to know if I can do better with batch/bulk insert.

I understand MS SQL server Bulk insert works on CSV files and these have to be accessed locally or via CIFS/SMB..etc.

**EDIT**
removed the link about executemany being simple loop since that was from pymssql rather than pyodbc.

Comment: The link in your question points to pymssql code, not pyodbc code. pymssql and pyodbc are different products. It appears that you are indeed using pyodbc, but are you using the latest version (currently 4.0.23) along with `fast_executemany = True`?

Comment: @GordThompson I realized that thanks. Yep I am using most recent and I set fast_executemany to True yet insertion is very slow.

Comment: It might help to see your actual code.

Comment: Is it possible to get SQL Profiler to show you what's happening at the server? With `fast_executemany = False` you should see individual `sp_prepexec` calls for each insert, but with `fast_executemany = True` you should see one `sp_prepare` followed by a number of `sp_execute` calls.

Comment: @GordThompson any ideas how to grab SQL profiler? This is SQL DB PaaS offering in Azure.

Comment: I tried again with fast_executemany = True and it ran super fast. Not sure where the high latency was coming from.

Answer (score -3):

It's true: executemany doesn't batch inserts for pyodbc. You can use multi-value inserts or call bcp as shell command. Hope, it will be fixed in nearest future. The insertion speed also depends on table structure and underlying hardware.

Comment: are you sure now about that since when I set `fast_executemany` to True it ran fast and that solved my issue?

Comment: *"executemany doesn't batch inserts for pyodbc"* - For current versions of pyodbc and Microsoft's "ODBC Driver x for SQL Server", `fast_executemany = True` does indeed enable batching of INSERTs by using ODBC parameter arrays.